# Сравнение отрицательных чисел

Tags: python, сравнение

Подскажите, где я ошибся, что у меня -3 > -2  это True!!!

вот код:

```
a = input()
a = a.strip()
a = a.split(' ')
x, z = 0, 0
for i in a:
    if x > 0:
        if i > z:
            print(i > z, i, z)
            print(i + ' ', end='')
    x += 1
    z = i
    print('-----------------------')
```

Суть проблемы, в отрицательных числах.
У меня почему-то продолжают выводиться числа в последовательности:
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
вывод:
-2 -3 -4 -5 -6
Как?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: a = map(int, a.split(' '))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

к целочисленному типу приведите сначала элементы, у вас сейчас строки сравниваются

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input()
a = a.strip()
a = a.split(' ')
a=list(map(int, a)) # преобразуем к целому типу каждый элемент списка
x, z = 0, 0
for i in a:
    if x > 0:
        if i > z:
            print(i > z, i, z)
            print(f'{i} ', end='')
    x += 1
    z = i
    print('-----------------------')
```

Comment: Спасибо, по факту - помогла "a=list(map(int, a))"

Answer (score 0):

Функция input() возвращает строку.
Чтобы всё правильно работало тебе нужно после вызова метода .split(' ') преобразить все строки содержащиеся в листе в числовые значения методом int()